# Using auth.login with authentication backed(error)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I created an authentication backend:

```
from login.models import zUser
import hashlib

class AuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None): #переписана функція для пошуку користувача в таблиці zusers
        password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest() #хешування отриманого пароля в md5
        try:
            user = zUser.objects.get(userpass = password, login = username)
        except zUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user

    def get_user(self, user_id): #повернути користувача за id
        try:
            user = zUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except zUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user
```

But in my view, where I call `auth.login(request, user)`, I have an error:
The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: last_login

```
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username') #введений логін
        password = request.POST.get('password').encode('utf-8') #введений пароль
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            user_id = getattr(user, "userid") #отримання userid користувача
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/') #перенаправлення на головну сторінку
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then I add to settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'login.auth_backends.AuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.ModelBackend'
)
```

But now there is other error:
Module "django.contrib.auth.ModelBackend" does not define a "ModelBackend" attribute/class

Update: Here is my zUser table

```
class zUser(models.Model): #модель користувача, створена по аналогії до таблиці zusers
    userpass = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    userid = models.DecimalField(unique=True, max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535, blank=True,primary_key=True)
    changeonlogon = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    userlocked = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    #crypto = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'zusers'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are your creating a custom authentication backend and login view? You can use a custom `User` model without having to rewrite the backend and views. Can you post your `zUser` model?

Comment: Why are you re-implementing a `User` object? Django makes it easy to extend their existing `auth.User` object with custom attributes (in your case, `telefon`, `userlocked` etc.): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: How will Django know that attribute 'login' in db table is username in custom Model?

Comment: Read through the link I posted. The very first thing it addresses is this point: `USERNAME_FIELD: A string describing the name of the field on the User model that is used as the unique identifier.`

Comment: ok, then same question what to do with password: in db it's userpass, in model  - password

Comment: using custom model, I don't need authentication backend then?